# Remove SAS 9.4 Configuration

Tags: configuration, sas

SAS 9.4 was installed and configured from a sasdepot with order number xxx.
It had a few issues with license file used so we had a new sasdepot with order number yyy.

In order to install/configure the new depot, we uninstalled SAS from our instance without un-configuring.

I am now unable to un-configure SAS from deployment manager because uninstall has removed the Home installation directory of order xxx.

Does the removal of /opt/sas/config directory (ie. configuration directory) un-configure the sas servers and other SAS products?

Comment: Stackoverflow is more aligned to answering coding problems.  Your best bet is to contact SAS Technical Support on this matter

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the configuration directory (or renaming if you want to save it) will remove the configuration. It appears you are re-installing SAS from the depot with the new order number. If this is the case, best practice is to run setup twice. During the first, do the installation. During the second, do the configuration. If configuration fails, removing/renaming will allow you to configure again without having to reinstall.